# How do I use LiquidJS Layout Blocks in Eleventy?

Tags: eleventy, ssg

According to https://liquidjs.com/tags/layout.html#Blocks LiquidJS supports Layout Blocks I can call from my Layout Template.

My default template contains the `{{content}}` block.

When I attempt to add another block called "sidebar" with either the `{% %}` or  `{{ }}` and define it in my .md file it does not render.

Does 11ty support layout blocks out of the box?

Answer (score 2):

So I got this to work, but it's a bit messy I think. While Googling, I found folks saying that with Nunjucks, they could get this to work ONLY if they didn't use the layout front matter but specifically told Nunjucks to load the layout (https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/issues/1467). So I tried something similar in Markdown (remember that Liquid is the default processor).

Here's test2.md:

```markdown
---
title: Test
---

{% layout main %}

{% block content %}
## this is test
<p>
{{ title }}
</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}
my sidebar is awesome
{% endblock %}
```

Note that I had to wrap my main content as well. Then in my layout, I noticed that: `{{ content }}` no longer worked. Instead, I had to use this:

```
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
{{ content }}
```

This *seemed* safe in my quick testing, as other templates not using the defined content block seemed to work ok. Just... be cautious.

Comment: As a followup, I wrote a blog post about 'additive' captures. The idea being able to capture 2 or more blocks into one variable. Turns out, this also makes it available to layouts. That could be easier, maybe? https://www.raymondcamden.com/2021/07/12/creating-an-additive-capture-shortcode-in-eleventy I plan on writing a followup based on this use case.

Comment: Nice solution. Works when I use .liquid files for content, but when i use .md files some of the template html is escaped and rendered in code and pre tag blocks.

Comment: UPDATE: when i use .md files that call my .liquid template everything--including the opening doctype declaration and header content--is rendered inside autogenerated html body tags.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this in my test. Auto generated body tags?

Comment: Ok I see what you mean - any tabs in the layout liquid file get processed via markdown as well and stuff gets escaped. I "fixed" that by removing the tabs.

Comment: This post may help: https://www.raymondcamden.com/2021/08/19/using-liquid-blocks-in-eleventy-layouts